# Изменить заголовок(ссылку) на textbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Добрый день! Вопрос немного странный, но пришлось и с ним столкнуться. Есть обычный текст, я хочу при нажатии на кнопку изменить содержимое этого текста. Это реализовано в codepen (скрин ниже). Код там мне не ясен, помогите разобраться как решить вопрос грамотно. Спасибо!
[image: Изменение в codepen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В codepen это сделано путем подмены тега  на тег 
т.е. когда я нажимаю на карандаш у тега  накидывается класс со стелем "display: none", а у тега  наоборот уберется

надеюсь на js добавление класса при нажатии сможете реализовать